# Is $\xi$ tangent to the unit 2-sphere $S^2$?

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, manifolds, tangent-bundle

The question I am attempting reads as follows:

> Let $\theta$ and $\phi$ be standard spherical coordinates on $S^2 = \{x^2 + y^2 + z^2 =1\}$. Recall that $\theta, \phi$ are defined as
>
> $$x=\cos\phi \cos\theta,$$
> $$y=\sin\phi \cos\theta,$$
> $$ z=\sin\theta,$$
>
> and can be considered as local coordinates on the whole of $S^2$ except for the north and south poles. Let $P=(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2},0) \in S^2$ and $\xi = (1,-1,1)$. Check that $\xi$ (as a vector from $\mathbb{R}^3$) is tangent to $S^2$ at $P$. Find the coordinates of $\xi$ in the spherical coordinates $(\phi, \theta).$

First of all I assume that this point $P$ should have some kind of factor involved such that its modulus is equal to 1 - otherwise it wouldn't lie on the unit sphere. So for calculations I guess we take $P$ to actually be given by $P = (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, 0).$ From here I don't really know hw to approach this. For context, I am doing a postgraduate course in Lie groups and Lie algebras and this falls into the introduction of some introductory differential geometry. The definition of a tangent to a manifold we have been given is that it is a tangent vector if it is a derivation at $P$. If you could prove it using this definition that would be great. I would also appreciate it if you could spare a proof using another method if there exists a more intuitive way.

Comment: That point is not on the unit sphere.

Comment: I know the $P$ given in the question isn't on the unit sphere which I explained lower down

Comment: Okay, then don't write $P \in S^2$. It's in correct. Also, the problem shouldn't state it that way as well. If you don't start with $P \in S^2$, then this doesn't make sense. So which $P$ are you using? The one in the yellow are of the one in your paragraph?

Comment: I didn't write this, I was quoting the question I was given. I explained this in my post.

Comment: As I say the quoted question in yellow is what I’ve been given. Obviously the P in that question is incorrect, so as I have said, I am using the normalised version that I written in the paragraph beneath the quote.

Comment: If you want to show $\xi$ is a tangent vector at the $P$ in your paragraph, then just show,

$$\nabla(x^2+y^2+z^2)\Bigr|_P \cdot\xi = 0$$

Comment: The quoted value for $P$ is an obvious typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\xi$ is a tangent vector to the unit sphere at $P$ if and only if $\xi \cdot \vec{OP}=0.$ Since $(1,-1,1)\cdot \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0\right)= 0$ we can say that $\xi=(1,-1,1)$ is a tangent vector to the unit sphere at the point $P\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0\right).$

Now, how to write $\xi=(1,-1,1)$ in spherical coordinates? We have $$\sqrt{3}(\cos\phi \cos\theta,\sin\phi \cos\theta,\sin\theta)=(1,-1,1).$$ If we consider third coordinates we have $\sin\theta=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 3}\implies \theta =\arcsin \dfrac{1}{\sqrt 3}.$ Now, from

$$\sqrt 3\cos\phi \cos \arcsin \dfrac{1}{\sqrt 3}=1$$ we get $$\phi=\arccos \dfrac{1}{\sqrt 3 \cos \arcsin \dfrac{1}{\sqrt 3}}.$$